# Postfix mail server not sending email

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, email, postfix

I had a postfix server that I had to restore from a backup and deploy onto a new server. Using the new server, the domain name is not allowing me to send email. I am able to receive emails but sending them just never delivers them to the receiver. How can I troubleshoot and solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You might first start with `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/log/mail.err`.

Comment: I checked mail.log and none of the test emails were displayed there

Comment: That would certainly be a good thing to follow up on. Why are your test messages not logged?

Comment: How did you test the sending of emails? I would suggest to do it by command line, e.g. this sends a mail to root: ```echo -e "Subject:I am a test email \n\n ... with a body\n" | sendmail -v```. This could be a good start for further investigations.

Comment: I can send email fine using a send function I developed with SMTPlib in one python program but it stops sending mail in another for some reason